# Template a terraform.tfvars file with command line arguments

Tags: terraform

I'm attempting to create a cron-based lambda function, and want to pass the lambda-name and rate parameters to the .tfvars file. Currently I have this hard-coded inside of .tfvars

```
function_name = "lambda1"
rate = "rate(1 day)"
```

How can I change this to accept command line arguments? Ie. something like

```
function_name = $1
rate = $2
```

Comment: The vars are command line arguments. You would be wrapping command line arguments inside of command line arguments. Is there an unusual usage here not described in the question?

Comment: Appreciate the reply! I am new to terraform, and don't think there is unusual usage. Have referenced this for help -> https://build5nines.com/use-terraform-input-variables-to-parameterize-infrastructure-deployments/

If i pass something like

terraform plan \
-var 'function_name=$(function_name)' -var 'rate=$(rate)'

Would i be able to use function_name or rate within the other .tf files?

Comment: Not in a way you have specified value assignment, but if done properly then yes. Variables are use as placeholders and are replaced with values you provide. It can be thought of as variables passed to functions in programming languagues.